# Banknotes and Coins working in calculator but not on program

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to sent this to URI but got 10% wrong. For the input 576.43 it gives 2 cents in the end. I did all the math in calculator exactly as my code and got 3 cents in the end. What is wrong?

```
total = float(input())
bill100 = int((total) / 100)
total = ((total) - (bill100*100))
bill50 = int((total)/50)
total = (total - (bill50*50))
bill20 = int(total/20)
total = (total - (bill20*20))
bill10 = int(total/10)
total = (total - (bill10*10))
bill5 = int(total/5)
total = (total - (bill5*5))
bill2 = int(total/2)
total = (total - (bill2*2))
coin1dolar = int(total)
total = (total - coin1dolar)
coin50 = int(total/0.50)
total = (total - (coin50*0.50))
coin25 = int(total/0.25)
total = (total - (coin25*0.25))
coin10 = int(total/0.10)
total = (total - (coin10*0.10))
coin5 = int(total/0.05)
total = (total - (coin5*0.05))
coin1cent = int(total/0.01)
print("BILLS:")
print(str(bill100) + " bills of R$ 100.00")
print(str(bill50) + " bills of R$ 50.00")
print(str(bill20) + " bills of R$ 20.00")
print(str(bill10) + " bills of R$ 10.00")
print(str(bill5) + " bills of R$ 5.00")
print(str(bill2) + " bills of R$ 2.00")
print("COINS:")
print(str(coin1dolar) + " coins of R$ 1.00")
print(str(coin50) + " coins of R$ 0.50")
print(str(coin25) + " coins of R$ 0.25")
print(str(coin10) + " coins of R$ 0.10")
print(str(coin5) + " coins of R$ 0.05")
print(str(coin1cent) + " coins of R$ 0.01")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that floating point math isn't exact. You can read about it [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). You are continuously doing division's with floating point values. You can fix this by doing `coin1cent = int(round(total/.01))`.

On a separate note, I think you should also look into the `mod` operator, linked [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).